# Change name to column R + loop function R

Tags: r, loops, matrix, vector

**Working on the built in "Sleep" dataset in R, but I am having some problems solving these two problems:**

**Problem 1)**
I dont manage to change the name of the new column.

*Create a new attribute for each student named "credit". For each student, the value should be remainder of its "extra". when it is divided to 0.5 (Example: extra: 0.8  remainder of 0.8/0.5 = 0.3 -> credit: 0.3)*

**My code**

```
sleep$new.col <- sleep[1]-0.5

print(sleep)

colnames(sleep)[4] <- "Credit"
```

**Problem 2)** I understand I will have to make a loop; any ideas of how it could look?

*Create a vector that will list values that are lower than or equal to 0.2. For each student, the code should check its credit value and should add its credit to the vector if it fits to requirements.*

Comment: Problem (1) `sleep$Credit <- sleep$extra %% 0.5` (see the help page `?'%%'`). Problem (2) You should really, really do your own homework. Think a little.

Comment: Thanks! 
Why didn't my change name code work?

Will thing more about the loop, but I'm stuck thinking about this as a vector, not a data frame with columns..

Comment: The change in your code worked, as you can see if you print either `names(sleep)` or `colnames(sleep)`. What is causing the confusion is that you use `sleep[1] - 0.5` when it should be `sleep[[1]] - 0.5` (which is wrong, by the way, it doesn't compute a remainder.)